# based on Session(UserType), display particular div on ASP.NET MVC Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view page that has two DIV tags.
`If the session[UserType] = ‘Guest’` , then I need to diplay Guest DIV Section.

```
Else
If session[userType] = ‘Logged’
```

, then I don’t need to diplay Guest DIV Section.

```
<div id="Logged" >
    <div class="txtContent">
        <label for="product" class="Form_Label">product:<em>*</em></label> 
        <%= Html.DropDownList("product", " -- Select one -- ")%>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Guest">
    <label for="DeliveryMethod">Delivery Method: </label>
    <select name="DeliveryMethod" id="Select1" style="width: 100px">
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="fax">Fax</option>
        <option value="mail">Mail</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: @Rita, don't forget to mark the answer you use as the correct answer by clicking on the Tick next to the answer.

Comment: Griegs! I first marked it and second time i wanted to mark more. :-) Something happened. That's why i marked it as Accepted answer. :-)
Really saved lot of time today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could do with either jQuery or a partialView.

My flavour would be to display a partial view based on the decision point.

Remember that your page shouldn't have any logic in it so you may want to write a helper to make the decision for you.

As an alternative you could render the page and then call a jQuery method that will return a partial view based on the parameter you send it.

If you require code please add a comment and I'll post some.

**Edit**

@Rita, if you're happy to have the HTML present on the page and you only want to hide/show the divs then here is the code for that;

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSessionValue" value="<%=session[UserType]">

<div id="Guest">
    <label for="DeliveryMethod">Delivery Method: </label>
    <select name="DeliveryMethod" id="Select1" style="width: 100px">
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="fax">Fax</option>
        <option value="mail">Mail</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then you have the following jQuery;

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
    if ( $('#hdnSessionValue').val() == "Guest")
      $('#Guest').show();
    else
      $('#Guest').hide();
  } );
</script>
```

**Edit2**

Based on the amount of HTML you have to hide/show I don't think a jQuery postback is required.

Comment: Yup. I need code. Thankks Griegs. Appreciate your time. I am trying to put my view code here. Somehow it is not displaying here on this Stackoverflow.


<div id="Registered" >
    <div class="txtContent">
        <label for="product" class="Form_Label">product:<em>*</em></label> 
        <%= Html.DropDownList("product", " -- Select one -- ")%>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Guest">
    <label for="DeliveryMethod">Delivery Method: </label>
    <select name="DeliveryMethod" id="Select1" style="width: 100px">
        <option value="email">Email</option>

Comment: I would prefer to go with the alternative way.i.e. load it using JQuery method

Comment: Thanks griegs. This is exactly what i want.

Comment: Awesome. I implemented. Worked perfect.